# how to start/stop tomcat 8 in redhat 7 using systemct

Tags: redhat, tomcat8

I'm running apache-tomcat-8.5.51 on RHEL 7.7 and are using a SysV init script to start/stop it. However, it seems that RHEL 7 doesn't use SysVinit to restart services after a reboot. Does anyone have the systemd/systemctl configuration for starting/stopping tomcat ? (And of course, RHEL7 stopped providing tomcat at tomcat7, not 8.)

Comment: Did you check with `chkconfig` if this SYSV script is set to autostart?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/houtianze/59b89ca71cc2029dd61d3c4bd86e6ee7 - This should help you out